# SignalR client method does not invoke

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I am still learning SignalR. In asp.net web Api I have created a simple hub. And in angular I have created a factory for instantiating connection with the hub.

```
 public class NotificationHub : Hub 
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            var x = "test";
            Clients.All.hello(x);
        }
    }
```

Client side.

```
.factory("NotificationHub", function(){
        var NotificationHubFactory = {};
        NotificationHubFactory.proxy = null;

         var initialize = function(){
             $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:18678/signalr";
             $.connection.hub.start().done(function(response){
                NotificationHubFactory.proxy  = $.connection.notificationHub;
             }).fail(function(error){
                 console.log(error);
             });
         };

         initialize();


        return  NotificationHubFactory;
    });
```

The problem is when I try to do this.

```
    NotificationHub.proxy.server.hello();
    NotificationHub.proxy.client.hello = function(data){
        console.log(data);
     };
```

`NotificationHub.proxy.client.hello` never gets invoked. Although if I put a break point in the hub  `Clients.All.hello(x);` it fires which means it can not find `hello` method in the client.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: What happens when you swap the 2 lines so that you attach the client callback before calling `server.hello()`?

Comment: `hub.start()` is asynchronous, so there's a potential that you're using it before it's ready. But if that's the case, you'd probably see errors in the console though because `NotificationHub.proxy` is null.

Comment: I do not get any errors in the console.

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach at least one event handler to the hub before `hub.start()` is called. Without that, the client is never registered with the hub. See this note from the [documentation here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)...

> Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method
>   to establish the connection. If you want to register some event
>   handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you
>   must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the
>   start method. One reason for this is that there can be many Hubs in an
>   application, but you wouldn't want to trigger the OnConnected event on
>   every Hub if you are only going to use to one of them. When the
>   connection is established, the presence of a client method on a Hub's
>   proxy is what tells SignalR to trigger the OnConnected event. If you
>   don't register any event handlers before calling the start method, you
>   will be able to invoke methods on the Hub, but the Hub's OnConnected
>   method won't be called and no client methods will be invoked from the
>   server.

Try this...

```
.factory("NotificationHub", function(){
        var NotificationHubFactory = {};
        NotificationHubFactory.proxy = null;

         var initialize = function(){
             $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:18678/signalr";
             $.connection.notificationHub.client.hello = function () {};
             $.connection.hub.start().done(function(response){
                NotificationHubFactory.proxy  = $.connection.notificationHub;
             }).fail(function(error){
                 console.log(error);
             });
         };

         initialize();


        return  NotificationHubFactory;
    });
```

Then replace the `hello` handler before calling the server...

```
NotificationHub.proxy.client.hello = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
NotificationHub.proxy.server.hello();
```

There's also a potential issue with this code as `hub.start()` is asynchronous and the calls can happen before the hub is ready.

Comment: Now works fine i have just removed NotificationHub.proxy.client.hello from controller and added it to the service.

Comment: However i can see OnConected method fires without attaching any event handler to the hub.